# SharedPreferences advantages & disadvantages in small application

Tags: android, android-sharedpreferences

Recently I discover on how to use `SharedPreferences` and I find it extremely easy passing data between activities with it. But I'm curious of its drawback. At one point I stumbled upon [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9025590/disadvantages-of-using-sharedpreferences) post saying that it's not good to abuse `SharedPreferences` if the data is big but I don't really understand what to extend big is.

Let say, my application retrieves some list of string using API such as user basic details, and user preferences. Is it advisable to use `SharedPreferences` to pass around these details? or I should just use some kind of database to handle all my retrieved data?

Comment: "retrieves some list of string using AP", for this use SQLite, and by small data means, key values, its good to save only small data, and states in shared prefernces

Comment: I would store user preferences in SharedPreferences. This can be easily done with key-value pairs. But when you retrieve something from an API and it's more complex I'd recommend to use SQLite.